How do I highlight all words in a vi file via "*" with the cursor on that word?
I need to highlight all similar words in a file. I thought * did this by default, but it is not working on my new Linux setup.

For what it's worth, I would recommend saving your .vimrc  somewhere (like on GitHub) such that you can copy it onto any new system that you work with. That way you will get a consistent experience across computers.

* in normal mode will search for the word nearest to the cursor. I suspect the reason you aren't seeing the highlight is that hlsearch is off. To fix this, use
:set hls

